# What is a good example of how to properly use MongoDB with Django

Tags: django, mongodb

Using Django 1.3.2 and PyMongo, I have found some random projects on github, and a few articles here and there, but overall, nothing concrete. Looking for good examples/tutorials on this integration.

Comment: this thread should be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972480/has-anybody-actually-used-django-mongodb/9306519#9306519

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if you want to use MongoDB and want to keep using Django-like Models and QuerySets, I can recommend [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the MongoDB docs for Python? Specifically [this bit](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#how-can-i-use-pymongo-from-a-web-framework-like-django), which links to an [example project](https://github.com/mdirolf/DjanMon)

Comment: i saw this example, but it has not integrated the mongo settings in to settings.py, which i thought was a problem, because it means that if you are working on a team with 1 > developer, they have to setup their mongo dbs separate (aka cant use django manage.py syncdb) and it could create some problems....unless i am missing something

Comment: If you're concerned with that, you could use manual python scripts, or define functions for use with Fabric, perhaps. That's one solution